# Excel run-time error 1004 after copying data from PDF

Tags: excel, runtime-error

I'm doing an extraction from a PDF file and pasting it into Excel, which it works great. When I try to process the extracted data I keep getting a 'Run-Time error 1004'

The code I have is the following

```
Sub PDF_Upload()
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fileName As String

    fileName = fso.GetFileName("C:\ABC.pdf")
    Title = Replace(fileName, ".pdf", "")

    Set objWord = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wdFileName = "C:\ABC.pdf"

    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(wdFileName)
    objWord.Selection.WholeStory
    objWord.Selection.Copy

    ' create new sheet and call it the pdf name
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.name = Title
    [A1].Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ' Close Word
    objDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
    objWord.Quit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    ' check
    Sheets(Title).Select
    ' process fails in the next line
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Everything works until I get to the last line 'LastRow = ActiveSheet....'

Any ideas on what is causing the error. I have look into other posting on 1004 error in StackOverflow ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702003/excel-runtime-error-1004),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282486/vba-run-time-error-1004?rq=1),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257359/getting-runtime-error-1004-how-to-stop-error/52258139),...), but I can not find anything that helps.

Comment: That line is overcomplicated. `LastRow = Sheets("Title").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`. The `Offset` from `A1` is unnecessary.

Comment: @BigBen, I've changed it as you suggested, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @BigBen: Your suggestion fails if the `ActiveSheet` is not a `Worksheet`. Better: `lLastRow = Worksheets("Title").Cells(Worksheets("Title").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: @Selrac: What does `MsgBox xlUp` put out?

Comment: Or use `With... End With` to avoid repeating `Worksheets ("Title")`.

Comment: @Alex MsgBox xlUp = -4162

Comment: @Alex, your lLastRow gave me the same error

Comment: @BigBen, thanks. I managed to make it work with With... End with

Comment: Great! Note that it's @AxelRichter not "@alex" - but glad your problem is resolved.

Comment: @AxelRichter, sorry misspelled the reference on previous comment. Thanks also for your help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments above managed to get the solution. Posting it here to help someone:

```
With Worksheets(Title)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Comment: Just realized that `Title` was a variable, not the actual name of the `Worksheet`. My bad on including the quotation marks around it in the comments.